# Improving a DbGeography query

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, optimization, spatial, query-performance

I am still new to database administration and I'm trying to optimise a search query.

I had a query which looked like this and took 5-15 seconds to execute in some cases, and also was causing 100% CPU usage:

```
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(3.3109015 6.648294)', 4326); 

SELECT TOP (1)
     [Result].[PointId] AS [PointId], 
     [Result].[PointName] AS [PointName], 
     [Result].[LegendTypeId] AS [LegendTypeId], 
     [Result].[GeoPoint] AS [GeoPoint]
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
        [Extent1].[PointId] AS [PointId], 
        [Extent1].[PointName] AS [PointName], 
        [Extent1].[LegendTypeId] AS [LegendTypeId], 
        [Extent1].[GeoPoint] AS [GeoPoint]
    FROM [dbo].[GeographyPoint] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 18 = [Extent1].[LegendTypeId] 
)  AS [Result]
ORDER By [Result].distance ASC
```

This table has one clustered index on the PK, and one spatial Index on the `geography` type column.

[image]

So when I executed the above query, it was performing a scan operation.

[image]

So I created a non-clustered index on the `LegendTypeId` column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [GeographyPoint_LegendType_NonClustered] ON [dbo].[GeographyPoint]
(
    [LegendTypeId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [PointId],
    [PointName],
    [GeoPoint]) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and changed the query to:

```
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT({0} {1})', 4326); 

 SELECT TOP (1) 
     [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
     [PointId], 
     [PointName],
     [LegendTypeId], 
     [GeoPoint]
     FROM [GeographyPoint]
 WHERE 18 = [LegendTypeId]
 ORDER By distance ASC
```

And now SQL Server performs a seek instead of the scan:

[image]

which in my view has increased the efficiency of the query, but when I deploy this to production, I still get the same results (high CPU usage, and average of 10 seconds to execute the query).

> Note: No data is inserted, updated or removed from this table – only
>   search/read.

1. Is it something I am doing wrong?
2. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

Index Seak details

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I changed the query, to use the method: 'Nearest Neighbor' from link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx, and now this is the result, This Query is also taking 3-5 seconds for the search - similar to the Second Query, (but not tested on Production)

[image]

Spatial Index settings:

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [SPATIAL_Point] ON [dbo].[GeographyPoint]
(
[GeoPoint]
)USING  GEOGRAPHY_GRID 
WITH (GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = 
OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
 DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
 ONLINE = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**EDIT 3**
I followed instructions by @MickyT, dropped the Index on `[LegendTypeId]`,and executed the following query:

```
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(3.3109 6.6482)', 4326); 

SELECT TOP (1) 

    [PointId],
    [PointName],
    [LegendTypeId], 
    [GeoPoint]
FROM [GeographyPoint] WITH(INDEX(SPATIAL_Point))
WHERE 
   [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) IS NOT NULL AND
    18 = [LegendTypeId]
ORDER By [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) ASC
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
```

Statistics for this query are

[image]

And then I executed this Query again:

```
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(3.3109 6.6482)', 4326); 

 SELECT TOP (1) 
     [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
     [PointId], 
     [PointName],
     [LegendTypeId], 
     [GeoPoint]
     FROM [GeographyPoint] --WITH(INDEX(SPATIAL_Point))
 WHERE 18 = [LegendTypeId]
 ORDER By distance ASC
```

Statistics for this query are

[image]

Comment: How many actual rows are returned by the seek?  Note that STDistance must be calculated for each row returned and the entire result sorted for the `ORDER BY Distance` clause.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've edited the question with the seek details

Comment: The query you are looking at is called a nearest neighbour search and is quite common but expensive.  Here is the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx) that describes the requirements for doing this efficiently.  This was from 2012,

Comment: @MickyT this Nearest neighbour seems to be performing the same as the second query

Comment: I would expect to see it hitting the spatial index.  I will have a better look at it in the morning.  What SQL Server version are you on and can you share the setting for your spatial index?  How many points in you table?

Comment: @MickyT I think it is hitting the NonClusteredIndex on LegendType because of the Where condition, and there are 54184 points in the DB, I will add the Spatial Index setting to the question. SQL Server 2012 - Enterprise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following setup to run some tests against.

```
CREATE TABLE GeographyPoint (
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    GeoPoint GEOGRAPHY NOT NULL,
    LegendTypeID INTEGER NOT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO GeographyPoint (GeoPoint, LegendTypeID)
SELECT TOP 1000000 
    Geography::Point(RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(MAX))) * 2,RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(MAX))) * 2,4326),
    CAST(RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(MAX))) * 25 AS INTEGER)
FROM Tally;

CREATE INDEX GP_IDX1 ON GeographyPoint(LegendTypeID) INCLUDE (ID, GeoPoint);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX GP_SIDX ON GeographyPoint(GeoPoint) USING GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID;
```

This gives a table of 1,000,000 random points with a 2 x 2 degree spread.
After trying a few different options on it, the best performance I could get was forcing it to use the spatial index.  There was a couple of ways to achieve this.  Dropping the index on LegendTypeID or using a hint.
You will need to decide which is best for your situation.  Personally I don't like using index hints and would drop the other index if it is not required for other queries.

The queries stacked up against each other

```
DECLARE @point geography;
SET @point = geography::Point(1,1,4326); 
/*
Clustered index scan (PK)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 641 ms,  elapsed time = 809 ms
*/
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
    [ID], 
    [LegendTypeId], 
    [GeoPoint]
FROM [GeographyPoint]
WHERE 18 = [LegendTypeId]
ORDER By distance ASC
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
/*
Index Seek NonClustered (GP_IDX1)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2250 ms,  elapsed time = 2806 ms
*/
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
    [ID], 
    [LegendTypeId], 
    [GeoPoint]
FROM [GeographyPoint]
WHERE [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) IS NOT NULL AND
    18 = [LegendTypeId]
ORDER By [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) ASC
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)

/*
For the next 2 queries
Clustered Index Seek (Spatial)
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 11 ms
*/
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
    [ID], 
    [LegendTypeId], 
    [GeoPoint]
FROM [GeographyPoint] WITH(INDEX(GP_SIDX))
WHERE [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) IS NOT NULL AND
    18 = [LegendTypeId]
ORDER By [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) ASC
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)

DROP INDEX GP_IDX1 ON [GeographyPoint]

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) AS distance, 
    [ID], 
    [LegendTypeId], 
    [GeoPoint]
FROM [GeographyPoint]
WHERE [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) IS NOT NULL AND
    18 = [LegendTypeId]
ORDER By [GeoPoint].STDistance(@point) ASC
OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
```

Comment: Should I remove the Clustered index on the PK in my table?

Comment: @DawoodAwan Don't remove your clustered index,  it is required for the spatial index.  The one that is causing the optimizer to discard using the spatial index is the non clustered index on LegendTypeID

Comment: Ok, I am giving it a try, are the settings on my Spatial Index okay?

Comment: @DawoodAwan  They look okay to me, but it really depends on the data that is in the table.  Since it is points there's not a lot of tweaking that can be done.

Comment: I've tested the suggestions you made - and I've added the results to the question under Edit 3, the number of Logical reads have increased from 452 to 4523, is this a good sign?

Comment: @DawoodAwan  Those statistics are behaving differently than what I am seeing on my machine.  I'm guessing that you legendTypeID has more than the 25 distinct values that I put in mine.  How was the performance?

Comment: Performance was not good - as there is no load on the DB server at this time but was still taking 4-6 seconds after I dropped the Legend index.

Comment: legendTypeID has 2 distinct values 16 and 18

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33343/discussion-between-mickyt-and-dawood-awan).